# Pulling together two results in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the result of one API (FourSquare) giving me this..

```
[["4e01728f814d9dac7d52b93d","Bark Boutique",40.7143528,-74.0059731],["4d9f92dfaffda35d5db2a748","Bark Boutique",40.7143528,-74.0059731]]
```

I send these results to another API that gives me a result like this:

```
[{"4e01728f814d9dac7d52b93d":yes},{"4d9f92dfaffda35d5db2a748":no}]
```

What I want to do is compare the second results I get to the first and combine them. So I would get back:

```
[["4e01728f814d9dac7d52b93d","Bark Boutique",40.7143528,-74.0059731, yes],["4d9f92dfaffda35d5db2a748","Bark Boutique",40.7143528,-74.0059731, no]]
```

However some of the results in the first set will not all be returned in the second set. So I need to find out which ones are the same by the id[0] and then pull these out and combine them again.

What is the best way to do this in ruby? I have tried using map, but can only extract the data from each not both at the same time?

**Edit for real data:**

array2 =

```
[{"4bed4208bac3c9b692fcfde9"=>743.0}, {"4e21b6f052b1f82ffba120b5"=>789.0}, {"4b646071f964a52052ae2ae3"=>921.0}, {"4bb504a30ef1c9b6dbc2f412"=>99.0}, {"4b426369f964a520e3d225e3"=>80.0}, {"4c4f275651c2c9288af1859f"=>254.0}, {"4b92cb0bf964a520501c34e3"=>468.0}, {"4b425f85f964a52092d225e3"=>27.0}, {"4bd86cb6e914a593c92f53fa"=>512.0}, {"4e687a6bb3ad5d9197518ed6"=>622.0}, {"4b4447f8f964a5206cf325e3"=>73.0}, {"4b425ec9f964a52086d225e3"=>26.0}, {"4b484917f964a520184b26e3"=>328.0}, {"4b426047f964a520a4d225e3"=>37.0}, {"4c978b274f16b71312c2ce3f"=>253.0}, {"4b6de739f964a520769a2ce3"=>81.0}, {"4b48c8a8f964a520cb5626e3"=>167.0}, {"4bb475f449bdc9b65bcb0c10"=>80.0}, {"4c126e3c82a3c9b60ab0f9f8"=>739.0}, {"4bd8b0442e6f0f4754240808"=>210.0}, {"4bb61c6bef159c74ff6b75f7"=>231.0}, {"4b56243af964a5204f0228e3"=>56.0}, {"4b411f2bf964a52082c125e3"=>0.0}, {"4b48a60ff964a5208c5126e3"=>211.0}, {"4baded59f964a52031733be3"=>514.0}, {"4b40ce65f964a5205ebb25e3"=>124.0}, {"4b444648f964a52049f325e3"=>81.0}, {"4bb0eb08f964a520006a3ce3"=>376.0}, {"4f63b0b5e4b087553c2ae4fa"=>586.0}, {"4b9a86c4f964a520f2bd35e3"=>192.0}, {"4cb995490180721e03e09461"=>125.0}, {"4dc58ce152b1e8f9f7d7378b"=>955.0}, {"4b92c695f964a520aa1a34e3"=>20.0}, {"4c582015a7d976b0130cddee"=>484.0}, {"4c8ccb34509e3704d9533655"=>743.0}, {"4b48f87ff964a520096026e3"=>48.0}, {"4c1a1c70838020a137aae661"=>640.0}, {"4b894378f964a520e72632e3"=>55.0}, {"4e8b7820be7b1b0656b1f927"=>666.0}, {"4e02726dc65b8061424b59f1"=>78.0}, {"4b4261e4f964a520c6d225e3"=>57.0}, {"4ba55291f964a5209afa38e3"=>77.0}, {"4c714ddcb5a5236acb995252"=>473.0}, {"4b7451e5f964a520fad42de3"=>80.0}, {"4b490136f964a520a56126e3"=>71.0}, {"4d987f7961a3a1cd32aace42"=>1008.0}, {"4dbd63785da3ff58ec6192b1"=>622.0}, {"4b71bb30f964a5200b592de3"=>640.0}, {"4be6c014bcef2d7f476805e5"=>1016.0}, {"4bc762a32f94d13aebd2117f"=>577.0}]
```

array1=

```
[["4b411f2bf964a52082c125e3", "The Three Pigeons", 51.236318, -0.57055], ["4b444648f964a52049f325e3", "The Royal Oak", 51.23555937678702, -0.5702378403809515], ["4b92c695f964a520aa1a34e3", "Slug And Lettuce", 51.237156, -0.571021], ["4b490136f964a520a56126e3", "The Robin Hood", 51.23603403568268, -0.568686], ["4b425f85f964a52092d225e3", "The Guildford Tup", 51.237734, -0.5703823], ["4b48f87ff964a520096026e3", "The Keep", 51.234704, -0.572574], ["4b426369f964a520e3d225e3", "The Five & Lime", 51.236908, -0.573695], ["4b56243af964a5204f0228e3", "The Albany", 51.23687122552597, -0.5666781994529876], ["4b426047f964a520a4d225e3", "The Kings Head", 51.234176, -0.573656], ["4b4261e4f964a520c6d225e3", "The Live and Let Live", 51.238477, -0.573306], ["4b425ec9f964a52086d225e3", "The Star Inn - Shepherd Neame", 51.23501026190194, -0.5749610066413879], ["4cb995490180721e03e09461", "Prince Albert", 51.242471, -0.572899], ["4e02726dc65b8061424b59f1", "Bar Mambo", 51.236896, -0.577263], ["4b7451e5f964a520fad42de3", "The Rodboro Buildings (Wetherspoon)", 51.236624141592365, -0.5775332450866699], ["4b6de739f964a520769a2ce3", "The White House", 51.23463575311113, -0.5773776769638062], ["4bb504a30ef1c9b6dbc2f412", "The Britannia - Shepherd Neame", 51.233105063438416, -0.5760687589645386], ["4b4447f8f964a5206cf325e3", "The George Abbot", 51.235186599066246, -0.5779409408569336], ["4b894378f964a520e72632e3", "The Boatman", 51.23155028087051, -0.572927], ["4bb475f449bdc9b65bcb0c10", "The Keystone", 51.23437208365849, -0.5779758095741272], ["4ba55291f964a5209afa38e3", "Rogues Bar", 51.23763173808256, -0.5610001087188721], ["4b40ce65f964a5205ebb25e3", "The Drummond", 51.24133950313797, -0.5758380889892578], ["4b48c8a8f964a520cb5626e3", "The Stok", 51.24272843225208, -0.5718989403261525], ["4c4f275651c2c9288af1859f", "The Parkway", 51.248229, -0.569356], ["4b48a60ff964a5208c5126e3", "The King's Head", 51.24666037427897, -0.5728936419289142], ["4b9a86c4f964a520f2bd35e3", "Ye Olde Ship Inn", 51.225673503520696, -0.5796146392822266], ["4c582015a7d976b0130cddee", "Wates House", 51.2420380341127, -0.5908584594726562], ["4b484917f964a520184b26e3", "The Rowbarge", 51.25055105804697, -0.5729025186239382], ["4bd86cb6e914a593c92f53fa", "The Wooden Bridge", 51.248547, -0.58514], ["4bd8b0442e6f0f4754240808", "The Seahorse", 51.218605041503906, -0.569018], ["4bb61c6bef159c74ff6b75f7", "The Astolat Public House", 51.23704061748392, -0.5893993377685547], ["4c978b274f16b71312c2ce3f", "The Queen Victoria", 51.21475338935852, -0.567119], ["4bb0eb08f964a520006a3ce3", "Anchor & Horseshoes", 51.254823, -0.548787], ["4c126e3c82a3c9b60ab0f9f8", "The Garage Tavern", 51.261162, -0.586647], ["4bed4208bac3c9b692fcfde9", "The Cricketers", 51.254246288978116, -0.6047425123927289], ["4b92cb0bf964a520501c34e3", "Horse & Groom", 51.24614672635736, -0.5279016494750977], ["4e8b7820be7b1b0656b1f927", "Apple Tree Pub", 51.2460676, -0.61427766], ["4dc58ce152b1e8f9f7d7378b", "Royal Oak", 51.248792, -0.626987], ["4c1a1c70838020a137aae661", "Withies Inn", 51.21199, -0.621551], ["4baded59f964a52031733be3", "The Jolly Farmer", 51.194106, -0.558244], ["4e21b6f052b1f82ffba120b5", "Compton Royal British Legion", 51.21349872454546, -0.6290990092597657], ["4b646071f964a52052ae2ae3", "The Jolly Farmer", 51.27866916930163, -0.5856227874755859], ["4d987f7961a3a1cd32aace42", "White Hart", 51.25011, -0.636736], ["4c8ccb34509e3704d9533655", "The Harrow Inn", 51.213387, -0.6316709518432617], ["4b71bb30f964a5200b592de3", "Bull's Head", 51.253260091783105, -0.5042177438735962], ["4f63b0b5e4b087553c2ae4fa", "The freeholders", 51.194189, -0.603889], ["4bc762a32f94d13aebd2117f", "The Cricketers", 51.194975, -0.608211], ["4be6c014bcef2d7f476805e5", "Worplesdon Place (Beef Eater Grill)", 51.27501810816803, -0.6078529357910156], ["4dbd63785da3ff58ec6192b1", "Scratchers", 51.19211, -0.60234], ["4e687a6bb3ad5d9197518ed6", "Three Lions - Shepherd Neame", 51.19198564344851, -0.6023865938186646], ["4c714ddcb5a5236acb995252", "The White heart Pub", 51.200254, -0.603593]]
```

need to match the id 4e687a6bb3ad5d9197518ed6 in array 1 with 4e687a6bb3ad5d9197518ed6 value in array 2...

Comment: What does mean this notation '[0] "4e01728f814d9dac7d52b93d",'? Is it an array?

Comment: yes sorry it was printed with awesome print

Comment: Just type type an arrays without pretty print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array1 = [["4e01728f814d9dac7d52b93d","Bark Boutique",40.7143528,-74.0059731],
         ["4d9f92dfaffda35d5db2a748","Bark Boutique",40.7143528,-74.0059731]]
array2 = [{"4e01728f814d9dac7d52b93d"=>:yes},{"4d9f92dfaffda35d5db2a748"=>:no}]

array1.zip(array2).map do |ar1,ar2|
  ar2[ar1[0]] ? ar1 << ar2[ar1[0]] : nil
end.compact
```

**Edit:**
In the original question the elements with same key and also they have the same index, but from edited question I understood that index can be not identical. Then:

```
array1.clone.each do |m|
  result = array2.detect { |hash| hash[m[0]] }
  m << result[m[0]] if result
end
```

The `clone` is essential because the construction `m << value` modifies the object.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for larger sets of data... it seems to fail

Comment: Well, how I can say does it work or not if I didn't see the large set of data?

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) allows you to combine several arrays. The form using a block might be the one you want.

Comment: zip with block doesn't work properly, see here http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5044